# Django/Nginx : serving static files in production

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to serve CSS and other static files on my django app using NGINX server. So I tried to configure it. Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name redpillers.net;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/limited/REDPILLERS;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/limited/REDPILLERS/redpillers.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
       alias /home/limited/REDPILLERS/static/;
    }

}
```

But when I restart the service I got an error in the error logs file:

```
2019/05/22 07:26:44 [emerg] 11589#11589: duplicate location "/static/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain:15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name redpillers.net;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/limited/REDPILLERS/redpillers.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
       alias /home/limited/REDPILLERS/static/;
    }

}
```

You have `location /static/` two times in configuration. Just remove one.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the second `/static/` location and keep the first one
So the ultimate config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name redpillers.net;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/limited/REDPILLERS;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/limited/REDPILLERS/redpillers.sock;
    }

}
```